# pseudo clique with at least connectivity x and maximum weight of the nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs, clique

Let $G=(N,E)$ be a undirected graph of nodes $N$ and edges $E$. Each node $n \in N$ has a weight $w(n)$. The weight of a graph is defined as the sum of the weights of its nodes, i.e., by $w(G) = \sum_{n \in N}w(n)$.   The connectivity of the graph is defined to be $c(G) = \#E_G / (\#N_G \cdot (\#N_G - 1)/2)$ -- this measures the fraction of edges in comparison to the maximum possible number of edges.

Given $G$ and a number $x$, I want to find the maximal-weight subgraph $G'$ which has at least connectivity $x$, i.e., I want to find $G'$ that makes $w(G')$ as large as possible, subject to the requirement that $G'$ is a subgraph of $G$ and $c(G') \ge x$.  This looks like some kind of generalization of the clique problem; here I essentially want to find a "pseudo-clique".  Is there any efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: You are saying two things that compromise with each other - the more connected it is, the less weight it can have. What exactly do you want? Could you state your problem more formally (e.g. starting with "Let `G` be an undirected graph ...")?

Comment: @WhatsUp I gave it a shot, I hope that this will clear things up.

Comment: Yes, the question is now clear (with a small typo: in the formula for *connectivity(G)*, it should be `#E_G` instead of `#W_G`).

Comment: Howevery I don't know how to answer your question... the problem seems quite hard to me. In [this paper](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~barna/paper/icalp-final.pdf) it is stated that finding a maximun density subgraph with given lower bound on the size (equivalent to your *graph_weight* if every node has weight `1`) is NP hard. Not the same as what you're asking, but shows that these kinds of problems can be difficult. But if your potential application is Social Networks, maybe a greedy algorithm will be good enough in practice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is NP hard, because with $x=1$ (real clique) and the same weight for each node you get the  maximum clique problem, which is NP complete. You can try to find a reduction in order to use a SAT solver, or just enumerate the $2^N$ subgraphs.

Furthermore, unless P = NP, there can be no polynomial time algorithm that approximates the maximum clique to within a factor better than $O(n^{1 − \varepsilon})$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$. [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)

We can't even find a good probabilistic algorithm, unless NP is in BPP.

If your $x$ is fixed and $<1$, look at the following article:

[An Efficient Algorithm for Solving Pseudo Clique Enumeration Problem](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00453-008-9238-3).  Takeaki Uno.  Algorithmica, January 2010, Volume 56, Issue 1, pp 3-16.

It considers a variant of the problem with no weights, but you can substitute each vertex by a clique of size square root of its weight, if the weights are not too big, and then apply their techniques.

Comment: ah, thank you for the correction concerning the percentage. Yes I am aware that the problem is NP hard, but I was hoping that somebody smarter than me already thought about this and came up with an heuristic algorithm. As I am not really eager to bruteforce a graph with 3000 nodes and a couple million connections.

Comment: So relaxing the problem by saying that it does not have to be a 'real' clique but on e.g. 90% does not help?

Comment: @Sim Answer edited